# Reading from a USB device using bash and raspberry pi 3?

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, stty

I'm trying to catch the response from a device that is connected to the USB.
With this code:

```
sudo stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 speed 115200 cs8 -cstopb -parenb -echo
sudo stty raw; cat > /home/received.log < /dev/ttyUSB0
echo "Monitor started"
```

On port ready, send the command request to the device

```
echo -en '\x5A\x00\x00\x0D\x0A\x71' > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

then read the log and paste the response in another file converting it properly
xxd -plain /home/received.log > /home/output.txt

so I can show the data,
cat -v < /home/output.txt

But I'm needing something more stable, that code is showing me this error:

```
stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

which is weird, because it was working...

I would like to catch the response and store it in a variable.

Comment: which stty is generating the message? stty raw or stty -F ...?
Also, why do you need to set your terminal to raw???

Comment: I don't know the reason why is generating that message

Comment: I know, you already said that. But in your post, there are two (2) stty commands. Which one causes the message to display?

Comment: oh, the second one

Answer (score 0):

i suggest getting rid of the `stty raw`.

Unless you are sending/receiving special characters that the tty subsystem will process, which is unlikely - because you said it is working - you almost certainly won't need it.

If it did work, you might find some undesirable side effects such as:

- backspace does not erase a character that you miss-typed
- control-c won't terminate your process

and other things that you might rely on in your terminal session.

FWIW, i am doing a similar thing with Arduino to Mac, Windows (cygwin) & Linux (read from the usb/serial port) and i have not been tempted to `stty raw` in any of those environments.